# How do I combine my find and grep command to delete the files?

Tags: bash, grep, find, xargs

I currently have the following command which produces a list of files:

```
find . -type f | grep -i -f ./remove_list
```

This command reads a file called "remove_list" which contains a list of terms (actually regex expressions) I want to find in the output from the find command.

The above command works fine but I don't understand how to now delete each of the files found (especially as some of them will contain spaces).

I thought I could do something like this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | grep -i -f ./remove_list | xargs -0 rm
```

As I understand it the -print0 and -0 are necessary to handle filenames with spaces in them but now when I try to run the command I get an error message stating "Binary file (standard input) matches".

How do I read in a number of (regex) terms from a file so that they can be used as arguments in the find statement?

Comment: So is the `grep` command supposed to be operating on the pathnames found by `find`? Because that's what it appears to be doing here.

Comment: Yes, "find" finds all the files in the directory, "grep" then looks in the remove_list file and looks for any matches in the files that "find" finds.  I want anything that matches to then be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first command finds all of the files, you can pass the output through a while loop to delete each file.

```
find . -type f | grep -i -f ./remove_list | while read line; do rm "$line"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need `grep` to output a file list as well. Grep doesn't know that these are files: It just views them as a stream of data. If the files themselves don't have newlines in their names and are generally whitespace-safe, then you can do:

```
find . -type f | grep -if ./remove_list | xargs rm
```

The `-print0`, `--null` and `-0` arguments to various commands are for preventing errors due to edge-cases in file names, such as file names with multiple whitespace and newlines. The problem gets harder if you actually have to deal with those, because your `grep` command is trying to filter the names themselves. If you really need to do that, you may want to switch to a tool that can deal with each name individually. In shells with recursive globbing (such as bash 4):

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*; do
    # check if "$f" is a file and grep matches its name
    if [[ -f $f ]] && grep -qif ./remove_list <<< "$f"; then
        rm "$f"
    fi
done
```

As always, you can mimic this in `find` and a standard shell with the same logic, but somewhat uglier:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'for f; do
    if printf '%s\n' "$f" | grep -qif ./remove_list; then
        rm "$f"
    fi
done' _ {} +
```

Comment: +1, though I think since you're executing multiple `greps` anyway, you could do a simpler final syntax like `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -qif ./remove_last <<< "{}" && rm -- "{}"' \;`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU grep. You can use `-Z`:

> ```
>    -Z, --null
>           Output a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character that normally follows a file name.  For example,
>           grep -lZ outputs a zero byte after each file name instead of the usual newline.  This option makes the output
>           unambiguous, even in the presence of file names containing unusual characters like newlines.  This option can be used
>           with commands like find -print0, perl -0, sort -z, and xargs -0 to process arbitrary file names, even those that contain
>           newline characters.
> ```

And you also need `-z` for the input.

> ```
>    -z, --null-data
>           Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.  Like
>           the -Z or --null option, this option can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
> ```

So your command may look like:

```
find . -type f -print0 | grep -z -Z -i -f ./remove_list | xargs -0 rm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel installed:

```
find . -type f | grep -i -f ./remove_list | parallel rm
```

If it is not packaged for your system, this should install it in 10 seconds:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

To learn more: Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
will love you for it.